# Call createToken more than once as part of flow

Tags: stripe-payments

Is it problematic calling createToken as part of the Stripe elements/card v3 flow more than once? As part of my flow, I want to generate a token once a user has a valid card instead of on overall submit.

Comment: can you describe more in detail what you are trying to do --- i haven't seen a use case where multiple tokens would be helpful. generally you'd want to create one, and use it to make a charge or save to a customer, then create a charge.

Comment: I only am going to create another token if they change the card number or some data. But I can't have the createToken fire on the form submit, I want to createToken when the card is "complete." I keep it in the form, and then submit it with the entire form to the server -- I do a lot of validation on the server. Is there any harm if I have to call createToken 3-4 times? Is there an auth "hold" by calling it ?

Comment: That might look like 'card testing' to a payment processor. What I might do is run `createToken` after the rest of your form validation completes `form.on('submit',function({ /* do validation */ if(validated) { doStripeStuff(); } });`

Comment: So calls to createToken, do they do an auth hold, of maybe $1? The doc isn't totally clear on this point.